# How to open a link in a new tab

Tags: symfony, twig

How to open a link in a new tab using twig template language.
Here is my code to open the link

```
{% set link = getUrl %}
```

I tried this but failed.

```
{% set link = getlUrl, {'target': 'blank_'} %}
```

Comment: You should really enable debug mode when developing, cause use `{% set link = getUrl, { ... } %}` is incorrect syntax and will throw an error - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/y4rc5j)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{ path('_welcome') }}">Home</a>
```

Or smyfony 3

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{ path('homepage', {'_fragment': 'home'}) }}">Home</a>
```